# This problem shouldn't occur but for some reason it does

Tags: html, css, web

So what actually happened is I was making a e-portfolio for myself. I started creating the basic html layout you know like how every html document starts and then linked it with the stylesheet. But for some reason the stylesheet wasn't working. I thought that I might have made a mistake in the code (As I many times do) but no. I use vs code so it should have told me that I was wrong, then I tried it in code pen but it still didn't work. The problem wasn't of linking also, because I already had checked that multiple times and most of you who use vs code would know that vs code will help you link the stylesheet. The problem wasn't in my code so where can it be?

Whatever I read about in the articles I think that the problem is in the chrome because it is taking my stylesheet as cache, but I can be wrong what do you guys think if you know please help me out.

Comment: your css can be cached, so try to clear that. What is the code you are using to include the css?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jbadminton. It worked sorry for not understanding suck=h small think I am a greenhorn so yeah. thx